# call overriden method

Tags: c#, asp.net, overriding

I have following code:

```
public class CustomContentBlock : ContentBlock
{
    public override void Fill()
    {
        this._Item.Html = replace_dangerous_entities(this._Item.Html);
        base.Fill();
    }
}

public class ContentBlock : EkXsltWebPart, IEnumerator, IEnumerable, IListSource, IDataSource, ICallbackEventHandler
{
    protected ContentBase _Item;

    public override void Fill()
    {
        if (this.Dirty && base.CallBackCheck())
        {
            this._FillCount++;
            if (!base.DesignTime)
            {
                if (this.ContentID == 0L)
                {
                    return;
                }
                this.SetContentLanguage();
                this.ReadCachedItem();
                if (this._Item == null)
                {
                    ApiSupport.ContentResult contentResult = base.Connection.api.LoadContent(this.ContentID, base.Connection.api.CmsPreview, this.GetAnalyticsData);
                    if (contentResult.Item != null && Convert.ToInt64(contentResult.Item.ContentType) == 102L)
                    {
                        string pattern = "scrolling=\"yes\"";
                        contentResult.Item.Html = Regex.Replace(contentResult.Item.Html, pattern, "");
                    }
                    if (contentResult.Item != null && contentResult.Item.ContentType == EkEnumeration.CMSContentType.Multimedia && base.Connection.api.CmsPreview && contentResult.Item.Status.ToString().ToUpper() != "A")
                    {
                        string oldValue = string.Concat(new string[]
                        {
                            base.Connection.api.RequestInformationRef.AssetPath, 
                            base.Connection.api.EkContentRef.GetFolderParentFolderIdRecursive(contentResult.Item.FolderId).Replace(",", "/"), 
                            "/", 
                            contentResult.Item.AssetInfo.Id, 
                            ".", 
                            contentResult.Item.AssetInfo.FileExtension
                        });
                        contentResult.Item.Html = contentResult.Item.Html.Replace(oldValue, string.Concat(new string[]
                        {
                            base.Connection.api.SitePath, 
                            "assetmanagement/DownloadAsset.aspx?history=true&ID=", 
                            contentResult.Item.AssetInfo.Id, 
                            "&version=", 
                            contentResult.Item.AssetInfo.Version
                        }));
                    }
                    this.ResetContentLanguage();
                    if (contentResult.ErrorMessage != string.Empty)
                    {
                        throw new Exception(contentResult.ErrorMessage);
                    }
                    this._Item = contentResult.Item;
                    base.NormalizeBase(ref this._Item);
                    if (this._Item != null && !contentResult.Item.IsPrivate && Cache.Cacheable(false))
                    {
                        Cache.PutCache(this._identifier, this._Item, this.CacheInterval);
                    }
                }
                this.CreateDataSet();
                base.CatalogIconImageUrl = base.Connection.api.ApplicationPath + "images/application/icon_document.gif";
                base.TitleIconImageUrl = "";
                base.Title = this._Item.Title;
            }
            this.BuildOutput();
            base.SetClean();
        }
    }
}
```

But I'm always getting an error  saying: `stackoverflowexception occurred in mscorlib.dll` at `base.Fill();`

The class `ContentBlock` is not written by us.

Comment: Is there any implementation in base class or it's just an abstract one? Check it by a free decompiler like JetBrains or Telerik one. **UPDATE:**
For finding the reason exactly you should go into debug mode and hit a breakpoint at Fill line, then hit an F9 to go into next method, by inspecting the call stack window you can find where the infinite loop was started

Comment: And what is `this._Item` ? A field or a property?

Comment: Can you post the tip of the trace (e.g. top 10 frames)? It should indicate where the failure occurred.

Comment: Place a breakpoint on `base.Fill();` and hit F5 a few times, then look at the Stacktrace window.

Comment: Somewhere in the chain of inheritance, Fill() is calling Fill(), which is calling CustomContentBlock::Fill() because you have overridden it. This infinite recursive loop causes the stack overflow. As people have mentioned, check the stack trace to see exactly what is being called and where the infinite recursion is occurring.

Comment: The problem is that I can't debug in `ContentBlock` Because it is a dll file.

Comment: But you can debug in CustomContentBlock, right?